# SQL query to retrieve WooCommerce orders tax rate name

Tags: mysql, woocommerce

I export the Woocommerce order list for a date range using a Direct SQL query from the database. The problem is I can able to retrieve tax value by `_order_tax` post meta key where how So the Rate showing like `12.5` But How Can I add The tax_rate_name from the table
`wp_woocommerce_tax_rates` and the tax rate should show like`GST5% 12.5` for more information please check my image.

**Query:**

```
select
    p.ID as order_id,
    DATE(p.post_date) as order_created_on,
    cpm.meta_value AS currency,   
    concat(max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_first_name'  AND p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END )," ",max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_last_name'   AND p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) ) as 'Customer Name',
    ( select group_concat( order_item_name separator '|' ) from wp_filn_woocommerce_order_items where order_id = p.ID ) as order_items,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_tax_class' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as Tax_class,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_order_tax' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as order_tax,
    DATE(max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_paid_date' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END )) as paid_on,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_order_total' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as order_total
from
    wp_filn_posts p 
    JOIN wp_filn_postmeta cpm ON p.ID = cpm.post_id
    JOIN wp_filn_postmeta pm on p.ID = pm.post_id
    JOIN wp_filn_woocommerce_order_items oi on p.ID = oi.order_id
where
    post_type = 'shop_order' and
    post_date BETWEEN DATE '2022-01-01' AND '2022-06-30' and
    cpm.meta_key = '_order_currency' AND
    post_status = 'wc-completed' AND 
    cpm.meta_value = 'CAD'
group by
p.ID
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added bellow this using `_shipping_state`

```
( select wtr.tax_rate_name from wp_filn_woocommerce_tax_rates wtr where (max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_shipping_state' and p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END )) = wtr.tax_rate_state ) as Tax Name,
```